# Añadir márgenes a un widget en pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, layout

Me gustaría añadir márgenes entre widgets utilizando el gridLayout en pyqt5. Ahora mismo tengo:

```
#Mi layout
vboxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)   
self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

#Widgets
self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 4, 1, 1)

vboxLayout.addLayout(self.mainLayout)
vboxLayout.addStretch()
```

Me gustaría añadir espacio horizontal entre el comboBox y el label_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres aumentar el espacio entre widgets debes usar el metodo `setSpacing()`:

```
self.mainLayout.setSpacing(100)
```

Si quieres que sea solo en una dirección debes usar `setVerticalSpacing()` o `setHorizontalSpacing()`.

Si quieres establecer el margen de un QWidget solo usa `setContentsMargins()`.

Comment: y si quiero añadirlo solo a un widget, ¿tendría que crear otro layout para incluir ese widget?

Comment: @Adriana_0_0 olvida mi comentario anterior, no es necesario usar el layout para eso, debes usar el método `setContentsMargins()` de los  widgets, por ejemplo en el caso del combobox usa: `self.comboBox.setContentsMargins(50, 50, 50, 50)`